# What colors mean on storyboard interface builder constraints

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I have constraints on the storyboard with different colors, and just want to know what they all mean, and what the errors are.  Eg:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out the following on [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/ResolvinganItemsLayoutIssues.html):

[image: Red]

Red: Interface Builder uses red constraint lines to identify conflicting constraints.
[image: Orange]

Orange: Interface Builder uses orange lines to identify either a misplaced item or an item with missing constraints.

[image]

Blue: Constraints are ok, and not in error or conflicting

Comment: Note that red lines will not necessary result in the issue navigator explicitly listing "conflicting constraints."

Answer (score 11):

Yes you are correct, just adding some more details, that might be helpful

- **Yellow** - Warning
- **Red** - Error
- **Blue** - Correct

In case of Autolayout constraints when you get these this means,

- **Yellow** - Your constraints may change in runtime, or can affect your layout, its shows due lack of all proper constraints that supports others, but can run without it. You can live with it, if it really doesn't affect your layout. Though Xcode does suggest what could be affecting, like in image below

[image]

[image]

- **Red** - It comes when you miss any layout that is absolute necessary, your app will crash if you run with error in Autolayout. Though you might find our the cause of error,or missing constraint. In this case too Xcode too suggest you to add missing constraints automatically. See images below what Xcode suggests

I hope this is helpful.

Thanks.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Red lines don't guarantee that your app will crash.

Comment: @DavidGay In most cases it does